# 'ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h' file not found

Tags: xcode

How i can fix this

```
'ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h' file not found
```

and I'm installed the pods and clean, reopen Xcode

and same problem

[image: The issue in xcode]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Usually it's better if you embed images directly in posts (like I've done for you) instead of just linking out to them. I'd recommend adding some more information though to your question to make it more clear, as right now it's difficult to understand what you are looking for (without looking at the image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this error adding their new library from Cocoapods.

```
pod "ParseFacebookUtils"
```